# SQL big query script issue

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery, where-clause, cross-join

could you help me, I don't understand whats wrong with my WHERE. I tried several things but couldn't end to the right conclusion.

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(fullvisitorId, "-", CAST(visitstarttime AS STRING)) as session,
RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY CONCAT(fullvisitorId, "-", CAST(visitstarttime AS STRING)) ORDER BY hitNumber ASC) AS Rank, 
(SELECT MAX(cd.value) FROM hits.customDimensions as cd where cd.index = 12) as cd1,
(SELECT cd.value FROM hits.customDimensions as cd where cd.index=29) as division,
hits.hitnumber

FROM 
  `dl-training-bigquery.NDA_CHAN*******51.ga_sessions_20191202` as session,
  unnest(hits) as hits
  
WHERE division = 'fsh'
ORDER BY hitnumber ASC
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWTwv.png)

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`division` appears to be a column alias defined in the `select`.

This is not allowed in SQL (in general, not just BigQuery).  Use a subquery or CTE to define `division`.  Then filter in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reuse a column defined in the `SELECT` clause in the same scope (left apart the `ORDER BY` clause). Here, the simplest approach is probably to move the subqueries to the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(fullvisitorId, "-", CAST(visitstarttime AS STRING)) as session,
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY fullvisitorId, visitstarttime ORDER BY hitNumber) as rank, 
    dim1.cd1,
    dim2.division,
    hits.hitnumber
FROM `dl-training-bigquery.NDA_CHAN*******51.ga_sessions_20191202` as session
CROSS JOIN unnest(hits) as hits
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(cd.value) as cd1 FROM hits.customDimensions as cd where cd.index = 12) as dim1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT cd.value as division FROM hits.customDimensions as cd where cd.index = 29) as dim2  
WHERE dim2.division = 'fsh'
ORDER BY hitnumber ASC
```

Note that I simplified the `PARTITION BY` clause of the window function: I don't think you need string concatenation here, you can just use a two-levels partition.

I also changed the implicit joins to explicit `cross join`s. This does not change the logic, but makes the intent clearer in my opinion.

Comment: thank you for your answer by the way , this is the problem i encounter , Syntax error: Unexpected keyword CROSS at [8:1]

Comment: @erika: ok there was an unwanted trailing comma on the preceding line. Fixed.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer ! it should be ok but I can't get the result as I get a  "Not found: Dataset dl-training-bigquery:hits was not found in location US" . I used the right table with correct variables though

Comment: @erika: I can't tell you what your schema is... If that table does not exist in your system, the query cannot work obviously.